# How do I force TypeScript recompile in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have a project where other developers modify TypeScript files.  We do not include .js files in the solution, since they're autogenerated and build server is not happy if they're in the solution.

How do I force my VS2013 box to recompile TypeScript files into .js files so that when I get latest changes from my Typescript developers, my .js is up to date?

This is what the project settings currently looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rebuild the solution in Visual Studio 2013 all TypeScript files get compiled into their JS files.

Comment: I think the issue is, when I do a 'get', and a build afterwards, they do not get recompiled

Comment: @Igorek If **`rebuild`** works for you then you can configure the `build` button behavior in "Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run" to do similar thing. The default setting is that build tries to be smart and fast